# column charts first date cut issue

Tags: date, highcharts, column-chart

when i use highchart in my live site it cut down the first date of chart on demo server it runs excellent but on live it create problem here is snap shot for that

[image]

the first label date is not view properly on demo server it looks perfect but on live it create issue.
it should be look like this.

[image]

Any help will be appreciate

**Updated**

after applying your solution there is small gap between label and bar any solution for this??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase [spacingLeft](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingLeft) parameter value.

```
chart: {
   spacingLeft:50
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will apply it and update here if it works.

Comment: apply it to live site then there is some gap between bar and the label can have any solution for that? here is screenshot

Comment: You can use [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointPlacement) or set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) params. If it will not solve your problem, please supply a jsfiddle with your chart.

Comment: how to convert date 2015-11-30 into epoch time format because in fiddle it is not creating any issue but at server it creates issue because it is hosted on usa server so it creates issue js fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/6wtdtvx2/15/

Comment: because of time change it will create issue